# How to get the SPID in linux 2.6 from C++

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have a question: Is there some way to the SPID in linux 2.6 from a C++ application?  When I do a "ps -amT" I can see the threads in the process:

```
root@10.67.100.2:~# ps -amT
  PID  SPID TTY          TIME CMD
 1120     - pts/1    00:00:20 sncmdd
    -  1120 -        00:00:00 -
    -  1125 -        00:00:00 -
    -  1126 -        00:00:00 -
    -  1128 -        00:00:00 -
    -  1129 -        00:00:09 -
    -  1130 -        00:00:00 -
    -  1131 -        00:00:09 -
 1122     - pts/1    00:00:00 snstatusdemuxd
    -  1122 -        00:00:00 -
    -  1127 -        00:00:00 -
    -  1132 -        00:00:00 -
    -  1133 -        00:00:00 -
```

And then in the filesystem I can see the threads:

```
root@10.67.100.2:~# ls /proc/1120/task/
1120  1125  1126  1128  1129  1130  1131
```

So is there some way I can get the SPID from my application so I can somehow identify what my SPID is in each running thread?

Thanks!

/Mike

Edit: I should add that the PID returned from getpid() is the same in each thread.

When I add this code to my threads:

```
// Log thread information to syslog
syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "ibnhwsuperv: gettid()= %ld,  pthread_self()=%ld", (long int)syscall(224), pthread_self());
```

I get this result:

```
Jan  1 01:24:13 10 ibnhwsupervd[1303]: ibnhwsuperv: gettid()= -1,  pthread_self()=839027488
```

Neither of which look like the SPID given by ps or in the proc filesystem.

Also, note that [gettid does not return the SPID](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=345317).

Comment: Where does the link say that gettid doesn't return SPID? From the fact you got an error (it returned -1), I think you just got the syscall number wrong. 224 only works on some architectures.

Comment: Returning -1 probably means the syscall has an error. Look at errno. Are you sure you're calling it right? Using syscall() sounds wrong. Use a name (SYS_gettid) rather than a number anyway. syscall(SYS_gettid) works for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about [gettid()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettid)?

Edit: If your libc doesn't have the gettid() function, you should run it like this:

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>
syscall(SYS_gettid);
```

... or see [example on this manual page](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/syscall.2.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. c.f. latest edit, the gettid call doesn't return the SPID.